# I'm entering login page but again home page opens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, loginview

I'm entering login page ( Verifying the username and password )
  but Home page does not open, RedirectToAction not working
  again home page opens

```
   public class AccountController : Controller
        {
            Account _AccountProcess = new Account();

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View("Login");
            }

            public ActionResult Login()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Login(AccountItem accountItem)
            {
                if (_AccountProcess.LoginAccount(accountItem)) >> Verifying the username and password
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(accountItem.UserName, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Base"); >> main page.. RedirectToAction not working
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                }            
            }
        }
```

Comment: What code have you got in `BaseController.Index` ?

Comment: Why Jquery is tagged in this question? I don't see any Jquery.

Comment: base controller my main page and ajax code is working

Comment: @user3575477 Ok, show this code......

Comment: When you debug, are you hitting the expected lines up until the redirect?

Comment: hello this my all code ..Please see to the pictures

step 1
http://i.hizliresim.com/O2AQnz.png

step 2  base controller home page

http://i.hizliresim.com/1Pvznb.png

step 3

login controller

http://i.hizliresim.com/aq3kyd.png

thank you

Comment: I think you set your auth cookie incorrectly. Put a breakpoint to your BaseController.Index method and check whether it is called after login.